# "No such column foo on entity bar" error, but name matches WSDL and profile grants read/edit permissions on bar.foo

Tags: salesforce

I'm getting the "No such column 'foo__c' on entity 'bar__c'" error for users of profile type 'baz'.

I have checked the Set Field-Level Security on the object and can see that the field is visible for the user profile 'baz'. I can also see that it is marked as visible in the source code and from going through the profile > Object Settings > 'bar' where I can see 'foo' as marked as having read and edit access.

Also, when I grab the WSDL, bar.foo is inside of it.

Are there any other locations on the profile that could cause SF to not be able to find this field?

Answer (score 0):

If `foo__c` is a lookup/master-detail, the profile needs also Read access to the table to which the lookup points to. Otherwise you'd end with stupid "pointing somewhere but I can't tell you where, not even `Name`".

Similar if the field or object comes from managed package and user doesn't have license to it.